# How to represent html text as plain text in jsp page

Tags: html, jsp

I have a column name which contains html elements . I want to show them as normal text in the jsp page. But currently it's getting part of the jsp page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [escapeXML](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/escapeXml.fn.html)

Comment: or `<c:out value="${theHtmlString}"/>`

Comment: arg0="<%=currentCampaign.getName()%>" how to use escapeXml here..??

Answer (score 0):

> *arg0="<%=currentCampaign.getName()%>" how to use escapeXml here*

That's not possible using standard Java SE API. First [install JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) if not done yet, then add the following line to top of the JSP

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

then you can use `fn:escapeXml()`:

```
<input type="text" name="foo" value="${fn:escapeXml(param.foo)}" />
```

Alternatively, you can also use the `<c:out>`:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
...
<c:out value="${param.foo}" />
```